# Why doesn't Gradle use Maven repositories declared in the plug-in's pom.xml?

Tags: gradle, pom.xml, gradle-plugin

Consider I have made a custom Gradle plug-in which is available at `https://repo.example.com/xyz` and gets applied as follows:

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven("https://repo.example.com/xyz")
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.example:xyz-gradle-plugin:1.2.3")
    }
}

apply(plugin = "com.example.xyz")
```

Now consider I need my plug-in to depend on a 3rd party library (`org.something:abc:4.5.6`) which is only available from another custom *Maven* repository (say, `https://repo.something.org/abc`). I generate my plug-in's `pom.xml` accordingly:

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.something</groupId>
      <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>xyz</id>
      <url>https://repo.example.com/xyz/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>abc</id>
      <url>https://repo.something.org/abc/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Now, when I rebuild and re-publish the plug-in, the client code which uses it fails to build, because the `org.something:abc:4.5.6` library the plug-in depends upon can't be found. Apparently, the plug-in's `pom.xml` gets misinterpreted: the dependency information gets extracted from it while the `<repositories/>` section gets ignored.

The only workaround is to explicitly add `maven("https://repo.something.org/abc")` to the `buildscript` section of each project which uses my plug-in, which I would rather not force my users to.

Are there any alternative solutions?

**Update:** this has been reported to *Gradle* team as [issue #8811](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8811).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the *Gradle* team's response:

> There are actually good reasons for the behavior of Gradle:
>
> - Gradle places a lot of importance on the *source* of a dependency. For Gradle, `org:foo:1.0` from Maven Central and `org:foo:1.0` from JCenter are considered different things. This is why repository ordering and [filtering](https://docs.gradle.org/5.3/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec::matching_repositories_to_dependencies) matters.
> - Repository hijacking has been [demonstrated as an attack vector](https://blog.autsoft.hu/a-confusing-dependency/) and so having a system that effectively, transitively and transparently, allows dependencies to be downloaded from any repository is not safe.
>
> Because of these reasons, this is a change that is unlikely to happen.
>
> There are however options for your plugin:
>
> - [Shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) that exotic dependency into your own plugin
> - Motivate the owner of that library to publish it to a well known repository, or in your plugin's repository
> - Configure your plugin's repository to also mirror that other repository